# How to add javascript dropdown change?

Tags: javascript, html

I have two dropdowns so when I try to select `wilayah` dropdown I expect branch value change depend on `wilayah` dropdown

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
    Wilayah 
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <select class="form-control" id="WilayahDropdown" name="PrmWilayah" style="text-align: center"></select>
                @*<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="parambranch" name="parambranch">*@
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-institution fa fa-institution"></span>
                </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

                                            
<div class="col-sm-4">
    Branch
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group date">
            <select class="form-control" id="BranchDropdown" name="PrmBranch" style="text-align: center"></select>
            @*<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="parambranch" name="parambranch">*@
            <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-institution fa fa-institution"></span>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Search" name="" />
    </div>
</div>

<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.datesearch" id="btnsearch"/>
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.wilayahsearch" id="btnWilayahsearch" />
<input type="hidden" value="@ViewBag.branchsearch" id="btnbranchsearch" />
```

This is the javascript

```
var Wilayahsearch = $("#btnWilayahsearch").val();
var branchsearch = $("#btnbranchsearch").val();

if (Wilayahsearch.length > 0) {
  if (Wilayahsearch == "-1") {
    getWilayah();
    getBranchWil();
  } else if (branchsearch != "-1") {
    getbranchselect(branchsearch);
    getwilayahselect(Wilayahsearch);
  } else if (Wilayahsearch != "-1") {
    getwilayahselect(Wilayahsearch);
    getBranchWil();
  }
}
```

I've already tried this but i have to click search button first to change branch value

Comment: Please reformat your html code, so the horizontal scrollbar is small as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Just bind onChnage event on your Wilayahsearch input,

try this :

```
$('#btnWilayahsearch').on('change', function() {
    onChangeWilayah();
});
function onChangeWilayah () {
    if (Wilayahsearch.length > 0) {
        if (branchsearch != "-1") {
            getbranchselect(branchsearch);
            getwilayahselect(Wilayahsearch)
        } else if (Wilayahsearch != "-1") {
            getwilayahselect(Wilayahsearch);
            getBranchWil();
        } else {
            getWilayah();
            getBranchWil();
        }
    }
}
```